# How do the Facebook like button and Google +1 button deal with a redirected url?

Tags: seo, facebook-like, http-status-code-301, friendly-url, google-plus-one

My current url format is like this:
http://www.wunderwedding.com/weddingvenues/venues/343/venue-name
I want to rewrite my urls to a more friendly format:
http://www.wunderwedding.com/weddingvenues/venue-name-343

Of course I will have to 301 redirect the old url to the new url.
But what happens with the Facebook likes and Google+1 that users have already given to the old url? Will those be maintained?

Comment: It doesn't look that much more friendly. Why make the change and take the hit of losing social shares and a slight ranking loss from the 301s?

Comment: I want to get rid of the duplicate names in the URL "weddingvenues" and then again "venues", the url becomes unnecessarily long. A slight ranking loss from 301s? I thought a 301 passes all linkjuice as is to the new page?

Comment: No, Matt Cutts has said a few times there is a slight loss of link juice.